# Inserting/Updating rows with some columns and preserve values of others

Tags: c#, mysql

A little background information: I have a table called `table_a`, which has 12 columns. I want to insert or update rows with values for 6 of these columns, while I don't wanna lose the data in the other 6 columns. And I wanna do this with a parameterized query in C#.

*field1 is Unique.*

```
> SELECT * FROM table_a;

+----+--------+--------+---+---------+---------+
| Id | field1*| field2 |...|field11 | field12 |
+----+--------+--------+---+---------+---------+
|  1 | AA     | BB     |...| KK      | LL      |
|  2 | AA     | BB     |...| KK      | LL      |
|  3 | AA     | BB     |...| KK      | LL      |
|  4 | AA     | BB     |...| KK      | LL      |
+----+--------+--------+---+---------+---------+
```

The Problem is, my first thought was to use `REPLACE INTO`, unfortunately this will delete the 6 not touched values:

```
> REPLACE INTO table_a (field1, ..., field6) VALUES ('AA', ...);
> REPLACE INTO table_a (field1, ..., field6) VALUES ('AB', ...);

+----+--------+--------+---+---------+---------+
| Id | field1*| field2 |...| field11 | field12 |
+----+--------+--------+---+---------+---------+
|  1 | AA     | BB     |...| NULL    | NULL    |
|  2 | AB     | BB     |...| NULL    | NULL    |
|  3 | AC     | BB     |...| KK      | LL      |
|  4 | AD     | BB     |...| KK      | LL      |
+----+--------+--------+---+---------+---------+
```

My second thought was to use `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, but then I'd have to bind the parameters a second time, the first time in the `INSERT` part and the second time in the `UPDATE` part, like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_a (field1, ..., field6)
VALUES(?, ..., ?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
field1 = ?, ..., field6 = ?;
```

That would preserve my data, but I have to bind the parameters twice.

The third option would be to create another two queries and use the `SELECT` and `INSERT INTO`/`UPDATE` pattern.

So, my question is, how do I do this the smart way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second option sounds like a winner for single row updates.

Your third option is good if you insert/update many rows at once (as it will not matter much that you have two queries then - providing each does only what it is supposed to do).

**UPDATE:**
Digging through documentation one finds that you can bind once if you wish - you can refer to the originally bound values with [VALUES()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values)

**UPDATE2:**
Well, actually you can not get to the bound values with VALUES(column), so instead two suggestions that actually might help:

- did you check about using [named parameters](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Parameters.html) (then you would not need to bound them twice)?
- did you consider stored procedures?

Comment: Named parameters seem like the way to go. Unfortunately I'm sitting on an ODBC-Driver which doesn't support it. But I think I'll go with the `INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY` anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've listed all the available options, along with the pros/cons of each. As for the third option, you would probably want to wrap your two queries in a [transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/commit.html) to ensure that the operation remains [atomic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_%28database_systems%29).

Answer (score 0):

Hi let's say you want to modify field2 to field6.

why wouldn't you do:

```
replace into table_a select field1,new_value2,...,new_value6,field7,...,field12 from table_a where field1=filter_field1;
```

You put the new values and you get the others value by querying the table you're updating.